# Constant term omitted without specifying "nocons" in Stata

Tags: stata

I ran a logit regression and the constant term was missing. How can this be?

```
xtlogit vigact3 years years2 marpart logass RS RL i.time, fe
```

this produces an output with no constant.. and I want a constant!

Also I actually don't know if I should use , fe vce(cluster id) since I am dealing with a panel dataset with individuals. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This may better be asked on [stats.SE], but the short answer is this: in a fixed-effects model everything that is constant within a panel unit necessarily gets eliminated from the regression model, as it is *constant* (see e.g. [here](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/128251-xtlogit-fe-no-constant-term)). You may want to read some background material on why this is the case.

Comment: But I have made other fixed effects estimation where the constant term does not disappear.

Comment: The intercept in other FE panel commands is [not really an intercept](https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/intercept-in-fixed-effects-model/), and doesn't really have a solid interpretation. I wish Stata was more explicit about this. `xtreg, fe` is really `clogit` under the hood, so you can do  `clogit depvar indepvars, group(id) cluster(clustvar)` or you can boostrap/jacknife the `xtreg, fe`.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov Thank you, what I do not understand is that the command "xtivreg y x, fe vce(cluster id)" and "xtreg (the same)"  gives me a constant but "xtlogit y x, fe" does not. Also I thought maybe I had to use "vce(cluster id)" to get the constant term but that as not allowed in "xtlogit". I feel like my coefficients are way too big in my "xtlogit" model, but maybe I should just accept my results ? (my results are kind of bad compared to what I should have gotten.

Comment: @EmilKrabbe Did you mean xtreg? Otherwise the comparison does not make much sense. The link above explains where the constant comes from. Clustering is about adjusting the standard errors. It has nothing to do with the constant. The conditional logit command I mentioned will allow you to cluster. Logit coefficients are not really interpretable or comparable to xtreg on their own. You should use margins to get marginal effects on the probability scale.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov I did mean ´xtlogit,fe´. In this ´xtlogit´-model I get coefficients that are way above ´1´ in absolute value on some of my ´indepvars´... . Is this a problem do you know? My ´depvar´ can only take values ´0 or 1´ 

I just naively thought that adding "vce(cluster id)" might give me a constant term... And no I did mean "xtlogit". I made a model using "xtivreg y x, fe"  where Stata included a constant term, and then I made a "xtlogit y x, fe" where Stata does not include a constant... I just do not understand why one model have a constant and the other does not.

Comment: Logit coefficients are can be anywhete on the real line. It sounds like you need to spend some time on nonpanel logits, then understand the FE linear panel model, and only then tackle the panel logit. Without those fundamentals, you can't skip to the advanced stuff. Also, xtivreg is not the same as xtreg.

Comment: The constant issue is explained in the two links above. Spend some time reading them and come back with details on what is not clear.

Comment: I read them now and I understand that the constant term is not really a constant term but averages of fixed effects on some assumptions. Okay so in a `xtlogit` model no such average of fixed effects can be found? and that is why I only get such "average/constant" when using `xtivreg`

Comment: @EmilKrabbe That is correct.

Comment: I still think it is strange that two FE models give such different results: one includes pseudo constant and one does not.